# Nginx page rendering behavior

Tags: nginx

What is set in my Nginx is it will serve my NodeJS app when the URL is entered in desktop and my VueJS app if it is in mobile.. Unexpectedly, it became a requirement that our desktop NodeJS app can also be shown in mobile vice versa. My nginx configuration is working fine but what is bugging me is when I switch from mobile to desktop it will not right away switch the page to the desktop. But you need to hit refresh before it is rendered. I don't know why...

**Take note**:

That when switching from desktop to mobile it works quite well

There must be something that I don't understand in Nginx

**Here is my nginx conf:**

```
map $http_user_agent $is_desktop {
    default 0;
    ~*linux.*android|windows\s+(?:ce|phone) 0; # exceptions to the rule
    ~*spider|crawl|slurp|bot 1; # bots
    ~*windows|linux|os\s+x\s*[\d\._]+|solaris|bsd 1; # OSes
}

map $is_desktop $is_mobile {
    1 0;
    0 1;
}

server {
    return 404;
}


server {

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    port_in_redirect off;
    charset utf-8;
    if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})") {
        set $year $1;
        set $month $2;
        set $day $3;
    }
    access_log /usr/logs/nginx/lion/lion.$year-$month-$day.log;

    location / {
        index index.html;
        if ($arg_desktop = 1){
            add_header Set-Cookie desktop=1;
            return 302 $scheme://example.com;
        }
        if ($arg_desktop = 0){
            add_header Set-Cookie desktop=0;
            return 302 $scheme://example.com;
        }
        if ($cookie_desktop = 0){
            root /usr/src/lion;
        }
        if ($is_mobile) {
            root /usr/src/lion;
        }
        if ($cookie_desktop = 1){
            proxy_pass http://marty:3000;
        }
        if ($is_desktop) {
            proxy_pass http://marty:3000;
        }
        error_page 404 =302 /;
    }

    location /dist {
        alias /usr/src/marty/dist;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /img {
        if ($is_desktop) {
            root /usr/src/marty/dist;
            access_log off;
        }
    }

    error_page  405     =200 $uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: If the URL is the same and only the cookie is different, the client probably thinks the pages are identical. I don't think this is an `nginx` issue.

Comment: I just solved it by adding a response header.. It's a cache page issue

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the answer by adding a `add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";`. It's a cache page issue so in the end my code is:

```
if ($arg_desktop = 1){
    add_header Set-Cookie desktop=1;
    return 302 $scheme://example.com;
}
if ($arg_desktop = 0){
    add_header Set-Cookie desktop=0;
    return 302 $scheme://example.com;
}
if ($cookie_desktop = 0){
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
    root /usr/src/lion;
}
if ($is_mobile) {
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
    root /usr/src/lion;
}
if ($cookie_desktop = 1){
    proxy_pass http://marty:3000;
}
if ($is_desktop) {
    proxy_pass http://marty:3000;
}
```